# Room doesn't autogenerate Primary Key

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have the following **Model** for my API Response:

```
@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
class WeatherEntry {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var wID: Long? = null

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_DATE)
    var date: String = ""

    @SerializedName("city")
    @Embedded(prefix = "location_")
    var location: Location? = null

    @SerializedName("main")
    @Embedded(prefix = "main_")
    var main: Main? = null

    @SerializedName("weather")
    @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
    @Embedded(prefix = "weather_")
    var weather: ArrayList<Weather>? = null

    @SerializedName("wind")
    @Embedded(prefix = "wind_")
    var wind: Wind? = null

}
```

**Weather Repo**
Fetches Data from Local or Remote Data Source, I set `forceRemote` to `true`, because otherwise there would be no data show in the first place.

```
class WeatherRepository @Inject constructor(@Local var localDataSource: WeatherDataSource, @Remote var remoteDataSource: WeatherDataSource) :
    WeatherDataSource {

   private var caches: MutableList<WeatherEntry> = mutableListOf()
   override fun getWeatherEntries(location: String, forceRemote: Boolean): Flowable<MutableList<WeatherEntry>> {

        if (forceRemote) {
            return refreshData(location)
        } else {
            return if (caches.isNotEmpty()) {
                // if cache is available, return it immediately
                Flowable.just(caches)
            } else {
                // else return data from local storage
                localDataSource.getWeatherEntries(location, false)
                    .take(1)
                    .flatMap(({ Flowable.fromIterable(it) }))
                    .doOnNext { question -> caches.add(question) }
                    .toList()
                    .toFlowable()
                    .filter({ list -> !list.isEmpty() })
                    .switchIfEmpty(refreshData(location)) // If local data is empty, fetch from remote source instead.
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetches data from remote source.
     * Save it into both local database and cache.
     *
     * @return the Flowable of newly fetched data.
     */
    private fun refreshData(location: String): Flowable<MutableList<WeatherEntry>> {

        return remoteDataSource.getWeatherEntries(location,true).doOnNext({

            // Clear cache
            caches.clear()
            // Clear data in local storage
            localDataSource.deleteAllWeatherEntries()
        }).flatMap(({ Flowable.fromIterable(it) })).doOnNext({ entry ->
            caches.add(entry)
            localDataSource.insertWeatherEntry(entry)
        }).toList().toFlowable()
    }
```

**Local Data Source**

```
class WeatherLocalDataSource @Inject constructor(private var weatherDao: WeatherDao): WeatherDataSource {

    override fun insertWeatherEntry(weatherEntry: WeatherEntry) {
        return weatherDao.insert(weatherEntry)
    }

    ...
}
```

**Remote Data Source**
This one definitely works as I'm getting all information from the api.

```
class WeatherRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(var weatherService: WeatherService) :
    WeatherDataSource {

    override fun getWeatherEntries(location: String, forceRemote: Boolean): Flowable<MutableList<WeatherEntry>> {
        return weatherService.getForecast(
            location,
            "json",
            "metric",
            BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
        ).map(WeatherForecastResponse::weatherEntries)
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface WeatherDao {

    ...

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(weatherEntry: WeatherEntry)
}
```

**Database**

```
@Database(
    entities = [(WeatherEntry::class)],
    version = 1
)
abstract class WeatherDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun weatherDao(): WeatherDao
}
```

All other fields work correctly, but `wID` is always null. What is wrong with my implementation?

I already tried to change it's default value to `0` and change the type to Int but that's not working either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try making the id non-nullable:

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var wID: Long = 0
```

**EDIT:**
I've found this in the sample code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceContentProviderSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/contentprovidersample/data/CheeseDao.java).
you can make your @Insert methods return the id of the inserted row object, so you could do this:

In your Dao:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(weatherEntry: WeatherEntry) : Long
```

In your refresh data method:

```
private fun refreshData(location: String): Flowable<MutableList<WeatherEntry>> {

        return remoteDataSource.getWeatherEntries(location,true).doOnNext({

            // Clear cache
            caches.clear()
            // Clear data in local storage
            localDataSource.deleteAllWeatherEntries()
        }).flatMap(({ Flowable.fromIterable(it) })).doOnNext({ entry ->

            val entryID = localDataSource.insertWeatherEntry(entry)
            entry.wID = entryID
            caches.add(entry)
        }).toList().toFlowable()
    }
```

Comment: when you do that the value cannot be null, what it is now?

Comment: then it's `0` or whatever value i set default.

Comment: how are you testing that?

Comment: I'm asking that because the id will be 0 until you insert the object into the database. AS per the docs "If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item."

Comment: well i fetch it from the api then display some fields of the items (including wID) in a recycler view, but maybe that's the cause. i will try to fix it in the evening and tell you if this was the problem. thank you!

Comment: It could also by a SerializedName issue :)

Comment: I checked my logic and can't seem to find an insert issue. wID seems to be set, because it has always the value i set in my `WeatherEntry` model, so it's not always `0` or `null`. what SerializedName issue do you have in mind?

Comment: The field name in the api is wID?

Comment: no there is no field in the api for wID, that's why i didn't put @SerializedName above it. but maybe that's a good idea and just pick a field i don't need and override it with autogenerate :D

Comment: ok nvm, that didn't work.. autogenerate doesn't override the value. how would you implement a field that doesn't exist in the api?

Comment: Could you show the code where you insert those weather entry object into the database?

Answer (score 4):

Read https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey?hl=en#autoGenerate()
, you'll get the answer

```
public boolean autoGenerate ()
Set to true to let SQLite generate the unique id.

When set to true, the SQLite type affinity for the field should be INTEGER.

If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item.

If the field's type is Integer or Long (or its TypeConverter converts it to an Integer or a Long), Insert methods treat null as not-set while inserting the item.
```

Answer (score 1):

solutions for my problem is change type of primarykey from "long" to "Long" (java)

> @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
> @ColumnInfo(name = "task_id")
> private Long taskID;